# What does the word "already" mean in this sentence?

Tags: american-english, sentence, sentence-ends

As I watched a TV series, I heard the following sentence:

> Will you fix your marriage or get a divorce ***already***?

I can't figure out what "already" means at the end of the sentence.

I suppose something like "immediately" but I couldn't find anything on the Internet .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It connotes a sense of impatience. i.e "Would you do your work already?"

Answer (score 2):

It is colloquial.

***Already*** stands in for "which you should have done a long, long time ago."

Answer (score 2):

The 'already' tag is characteristic of Ashkenazi Jewish English (presumably a calque from Yiddish) and, as such, has spread out from the New York Jewish population into wider American usage.  I think TheObliviousMe is correct in saying that it conveys a *sense of impatience*, rather than having any definable *meaning*. It is often (over-)used, however to caricature Jewish speech for comic effect.

Comment: That's an interesting cultural reference. Can you supply a link to the reference, please?

Comment: I have no academic source for this.  I have, admittedly, made a couple of assumptions here about its origins and propagation but there are plenty of examples of the 'already' tag being used as a Jewish cliché.  https://eatalready.com/tag/jewish-2/ https://www.amazon.co.uk/d/Books/Enough-Already-Mainly-Jewish-Funny-Me/0954265017 https://www.thenation.com/article/shut-about-jews-already/ http://blogs.timesofisrael.com/jewish-identity-jews-are-a-people-get-over-it-already/ http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0425046/

Comment: tchrist's comment on the question linked to above by Drew (answer 1, comment 2) mentions a possible Yiddish origin - although it seems that equivalent words to 'already' are used in a very similar way in several European languages.

Comment: Thanks for the links. I agree that although not conclusive, they are strongly suggestive of your assertion. +1.